# Writing a predict() function for the Smatr package

Tags: prediction

How to write a predict() function for the Smatr package (specifically for the sma command)?

Comment: Erm, I don't think we're here to just write code. What have you tried? Where have you researched?

Comment: Ian, I am a newbie to the R language programming. I have seen the predict.lm code and was overwhelmed by its complexity.